# Condición Where y BETWEEN para seleccionar rango de fehcas

Tags: php, php7

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error en la selección de rango de fechas.

> "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\eliteq_v1\app\controllers\IncidenciasController.php on line 99

Este es código que tengo:

```
if(!empty($request->incidencias_inc_apertura)){
            $vals = explode("to", str_replace(" ", "", $request->incidencias_inc_apertura));
            $startdate = $vals[0];
            $enddate = $vals[1];  -- ESTA ES LA LINEA 99
            $db->where("incidencias.inc_apertura BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'");
        }
```

Comment: El propio error te indica que no existe el valor del array que buscas, eso quiere decir que tu explote no encuentra el "to", lo cual el fallo viene de lo que viene en `incidencias_inc_apertura`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!